# JavaScript Composite String

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript equivalent to printf/string.format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format)

I'm not sure the exact term (string substitution?) but many languages (C, VB, C#, etc.) offer similar mechanisms for constructing string dynamically. The following is an example in C#:

```
string firstName = "John";
string lastName = "Doe";
string sFinal = string.Format(" Hello {0} {1} !", firstName, lastName);
```

I'd would like to accomplish the same thing in JavaScript. Can anyone shed some light?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript does not [yet](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/08/01/a-critical-review-of-ecmascript-6-quasi-literals/) have this functionality natively. You'll have to use concatenation:

```
var firstName = "John";
var lastName = "Doe";
var sFinal = " Hello " + firstName + " " + lastName + " !";
```

That sucks? True. But this is the world we live in.

---

As pointed out by @PeterSzymkowski, you can use [this JavaScript implementation of the C/PHP `sprintf` function](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf).

Comment: [World we live in is not that bad](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf)

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski - True, which is why I said that JavaScript does not support this *natively*. I'll add that link to my answer.